# Bootstrap - Why does the navbar not collapse at the default 768px breaking point?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm confused as to why the navbar does not collapse at its default breaking point of 768px.
In bootstrap's own example the navbar does not collapse at 768px.

I'm having a problem with this on my own website, and went and tested on bootstraps examples.

I tested bootstraps example page here in this screen emulator. I also tested on a real ipad. Both do not collapse at 768px.

[IPad - Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/&w=768&h=1024&a=22&s=1&p=1)

Comment: Was my answer helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap navbar collapse at **viewport width** 767px, this means your **window width** is 781px. If your viewport width reaches 768px or any higher value, your navbar will be displayed normally like you see it on any desktop.

**Width viewport 767px**

[image: Navbar collapsed]

**Width viewport 768px or higher**

[image: Navbar not collapsed]

You probably was confused by the window width, anyways, if you want to display the viewport and window size like i did in those screenshots, you need web developer addon for firefox, you can also see it in the screenshot, all you need to do is to press on that Resize button and pick `Display Window Size` but it also has other cool options like `View Responsive Layouts` or `Resize Window`.

Hope this helps.